# How to change order status for COD order after creating invoice with not capture

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, order-status

I have created order with status pending and state new when i am creating invoice with not capture than status is processing and same for creating ship. i want to change order status after shipping to shipped.

Answer (score 0):

i Got answer

create observer on sales_order_shipment_save_after event

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

        <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
            <observer name="tenx_sales_order_shipment_save_after" instance="Tenx\SalesExt\Observer\SalesOrderShipmentSaveAfter" />
        </event>
    </config>

create observer.

 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        /*$order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT, true);
        $order->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT);
        $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), 'Order processed successfully with reference');
        $order->save();
```